# Unity C# if statement broken

Tags: c#

'''I am trying to put together a code that loads the next scene after the enemy count == 0, for some reason, it keeps triggering the debug statement regardless of the amount given.'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class text : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI txt;
    private GameObject[] getCount;
    public float count = 7f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   
    public void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
        count = getCount.Length;
        txt.SetText(count.ToString());
        if (count == 0) ;
        {
            Debug.Log(count);
        }
        
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement contains `;` at the end, is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

> if(){ ... } not if(); you can check again